# Group by range of dates from date_start to date_end columns

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a table with following table structure:

```text
place_id            date_start       date_end
2826088480774       2017-09-19       2017-09-20
1898375544837       2017-08-01       2017-08-03
1425929142277       2017-09-23       2017-10-03
1013612281863       2016-10-12       2016-10-14
1795296329731       2016-10-13       2016-10-13
695784701956        2017-09-11       2017-11-02
```

I want to count how many events (each row is an event) was in every place by each month. If event dates refer to several months, it should be counted for all affected months.

`place_id` could be repeated, so I did the following query:

```sql
Select place_id, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_start) as 
month, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_start) as year, 
COUNT(*) as events
From Table
Group by place_id, year, month
Order by month, year, events desc
```

So I get following grouped table:

```text
place_id         month      year   events
2826088480774       8       2017     345
1898375544837       8       2017     343
1425929142277       8       2017     344
1013612281863       8       2017     355
1795296329731       8       2017     348
695784701956        8       2017     363
```

Problem is that data is grouped only by `start_date`, and its not clear for me how to distribute data by all affected months range from `date_start` to `date_end`.

Comment: You've tagged 2 different RDBMS which have their own bespoke date and time functions; do you know what platform you are using? Please tag the correct RDBMS.

Comment: You must generate year-month values list then join your data to it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name actually im using databricks notebook with spark sql. And as i saw for now, it supports everything what im using in postgres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`sequence`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#sequence) function to generate the dates between `date_start` and `date_end` then explode the generated array column and group by and count as you already did:

```scala
df.createOrReplaceTempView("EventsTable")

spark.sql("""
    WITH events AS (
        SELECT  place_id, 
                explode(event_dates) as event_date
        FROM    (
            SELECT  place_id, 
                    sequence(date_start, date_end, interval 1 day) as event_dates
            FROM    EventsTable
        )
    )
    
    SELECT  place_id, 
            month(event_date) as month, 
            year(event_date)  as year,
            count(*)          as events
    FROM    events
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
    ORDER BY month, year, events desc
""").show()

//+-------------+-----+----+------+
//|     place_id|month|year|events|
//+-------------+-----+----+------+
//|1898375544837|    8|2017|     3|
//|695784701956 |    9|2017|    20|
//|1425929142277|    9|2017|     8|
//|2826088480774|    9|2017|     2|
//|1013612281863|   10|2016|     3|
//|1795296329731|   10|2016|     1|
//|695784701956 |   10|2017|    31|
//|1425929142277|   10|2017|     3|
//|695784701956 |   11|2017|     2|
//+-------------+-----+----+------+
```